# How to predict a mathematical progression with keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow, rnn

I try the following model for a many-to-many recurrent network:

```
                              [170]     [682]     [2730]
                                |         |         |
       o  -------  o  --------  o  -----  o  -----  o
     / | \      /  |  \      /  |  \
   [2, 2, 3], [2, 10, 11], [2, 42, 43]
     {t=1}       {t=2}       {t=3}      {t=4}     {t=5}
```

The model should be the following: x1* (x2+x3),
Where [ x1=constant ]. [ x3=x2+1 ]. [ x2=x1* (x2+x3) of previous time {t-1} ]

This model should return the result of [ x1* (x2+x3) ] at times t=4; t=5; t=6.

Well, since this test model did not give me correct results, I decided to try it in the Keras and the result has also been wrong.

I leave the code in Keras to see if someone can help me get the correct results and explain why the model does not work.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.models import Sequential

# Data train
X = np.array([ [ [3,3,4], [3,21,22], [3,129,130] ],
               [ [2,2,3], [2,10,11], [2, 42, 43] ],
               [ [2,2,3], [2,10,11], [2, 42, 43] ],
               [ [4,4,5], [4,36,37], [4,292,293] ],
               [ [5,5,6], [5,55,56], [5,555,556] ]
              ],    dtype=int)

Y = np.array([ [[777 ], [4665 ], [27993 ] ],
               [[170 ], [682  ], [2730  ] ],
               [[170 ], [682  ], [2730  ] ],
               [[2340], [18724], [149796] ],
               [[5555], [55555], [555555] ]
              ], dtype=int)

# Model
def get_compiled_model():
  timesteps = 3 #times
  data_dim = 3  #features
  N = 3         #salidas
  model = Sequential()

  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(1, input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim)))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(N))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(1, return_sequences=True))  
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('linear'))
  
  opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.9)
  model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='MAE')
  return model

# main
model = get_compiled_model()
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=4000)

result = model.predict([[ [2,2,3], [2,10,11], [2,42,43] ]])
print(result)
```

The truth is that I tried this model using several types of layers in Keras (Dense layer, SimpleRNN, LSTM) and none of them have worked.

I leave an image of the loss curve
[image]

Comment: Can you include the loss curves for us to understand how the training went?

Comment: I added the image to the post